# I am new to WCF. I need to implement a WCF web service with callbacks/Events to clients

Tags: java, web-services, events, unix, clients

I know that this is possible. 
How to implement this for a Java/Unix client? 
Is it supported?

Any sample code will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Project Tango](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/glassfish/ProjectTango/) from Sun (Oracle).

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am looking for solution where i can implement Webservices in microsoft technologies. Do you think Project Tango supports developing solution in WCF?